# Curl и Https?

Tags: curl

Есть ли возможность получить данные с https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогает выключение опции **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER**, а так же опции **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST**:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

[Совместное испозование PHP, cURL, протокола HTTPS и Cookie](http://www.shkodenko.kiev.ua/index.php?lang_id=1&content_id=165)

[HTTPS запросы в Curl PHP не работают](http://zliypes.com.ua/blog/2008/01/25/php-win32-curl-https/)

Comment: Эй-эй, не надо же так делать! Нет никакого смысла использовать HTTPS при отключенных проверках безопасности.

Answer (score -1):

Немного непонятен сам вопрос. Если имеется ввиду получить данные по адресу, который начинается с "https", то Да. Этот протокол поддерживается.
А если Вы что-то другое имеете ввиду, то уточните вопрос.

Comment: это и имеется в виду. Но у меня данные не берутся по адресу, который начинается с "https"

Comment: Проверьте адрес. Я точно помню, что, когда используешь cUrl не открывается http://youtube.com , но открывается http://www.youtube.com . А страничка по адресу http://google.com содержит строчку о том, что эта страница находится по адресу http://www.google.com . Возможно именно по этому адресу не отдается страница?