# Получение изображения по ссылке (https) и загрузка его на сайт. (CURL)

Tags: php, post, curl

Всем привет.

$link - адрес картинки.

$site - адрес, на который загружаю картинку

```
$url['photo'] = new CURLFile($link);
$ch = curl_init($site);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url);
curl_close($ch);
```

Если в $link адрес локальной (/var/www/olo-lo/123.jpg) картинки, то всё работает, если извне, то не работает.
Как получить картинку по https минуя сохранения на файловую систему и сразу загрузить её на необходимый адрес?

Пробовал по разному, и получать картинку через file_get_contents() и без него, и использовать CURLFile() и с опциями и без них...
Есть только одно правильное решение. Какое?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/180099/curl-%d0%b8-https

Comment: Не то. Попробовал, не получилось. Я так понимаю, что как-то не правильно передаётся изображение в строку curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url);

Comment: А вы почему url в post данные пишите? http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php `CURLOPT_URL` для указания адреса обращения служит.

Comment: Не совсем понял. $url это уже объект от CURLFile()

Comment: Вы хотите файл со своего сервера отправить на удаленный?

Comment: Не совсем, а если точнее, я хочу получить файл (картинку) с одного сайта (https://site.ru/124.jpg) и загрузить её на другой сайт, при этом не сохраняя её у себя на сервере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз уж CURLFile работает только с локальными файлами, почему бы не скачать картинку на диск?

```
$link = 'https://example.com/image.jpg'
$link_local = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'FOO');
file_put_contents($link_local,file_get_contents($link));
$url['photo'] = new CURLFile($link_local,'image/jpeg','image.jpg');
$ch = curl_init($site);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url);
curl_close($ch);
unset($url['photo']);
unlink($link_local);
```

может понадобится поменять заголовок User-Agent, если сайт блокирует закачку изображений из php, и/или добавить заголовок Referrer, если сайт блокирует hotlink

P.S. скачка с https-сайтов требует включенную библиотеку `php_openssl` и опцию `allow_url_fopen` (и то и другое можно посмотреть в phpinfo)

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
allow_url_fopen = On
```

Comment: Но это же костыль... Записать файл на хард, прочитать, удалить. И так много, много раз.
Скачивается картинка без проблем.

Comment: @polger Ну, в таком случае "правильным" будет такое решение: получить файл **как поток** и, в процессе получения, отправлять на сервер. Как для получения, так и для отправки в таком случае придется вручную составлять запросы через fsockopen, либо использовать библиотеки... Простыня реализации HTTP chunked, multipart-запрос... На php всё это написать можно, но сложно.

Comment: А сохранять на диск как Вы написали не такая большая проблема. Отличный вариант. )))