# не работает curl_exec()

Tags: php, curl

```
$url = 'https://ntschool.ru/kursyi';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
var_dump($content);
```

var_dump показывает false , при попытке записать это на файл file_put_contents('1',$content ) создает пустой файл, не понимаю почему не работает, curl подключен ошибок никаких не выдает

Comment: вывод ошибок включен? в логах смотрели?

Comment: Получить описание ошибки можно так `$error = curl_error($ch);`. Есть подозрение что не проходит ssl-верификаци, попробуйте установить опции `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` и `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` в `false`;

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Curl и Https?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/180099/curl-%d0%b8-https)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ввиду того, что Гугл использует HTTPS, добавьте это:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо! это заработало

Comment: А можете ли объяснить что делают эти опции? из документации не особо понятно

Comment: @AntonKucenko отключают проверку подлинности сертификата сервера и имени хоста, которому выдан сертификат.

Comment: @Hombre остаётся непонятным: почему без отключения не работает?

Answer (score -2):

Вообще-то код работает. Все записывает как надо. Протестил. Ищите проблему не в коде.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://ntschool.ru/kursyi';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents('site.html', $content);

?>
```

Comment: Вы скорее всего посетили этот сайт в браузере, а уже потом запустили код, не так ли? ;)

Comment: Нет, просто все дело в прямых руках  ;) У меня код сработал и без отключения проверки сертификата в CURL, поэтому я и не стал упоминать данную настройку.